# Require.js independent on other websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I created a widget that uses requirejs.
The widget is there to place it into any website.
This means I have no control over any scripts that are loaded in this website.

The code to implement my widget looks like this:

```
<!-- Widget start -->
<script data-main="urlto/main" src="urlto/require.min.js"></script>
<div id="myWidget" data-auth="xxx-token-xxx"></div>
<!-- Widget end -->
```

Now I got same Errors in my test cases.

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [object Object]
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'easing' of undefined
```

Now I ve read, requirejs must be the first loaded script in the website. But I can´t control that. It depends on jQuery, this is loaded in the Widget itself via requirejs.
Problem is, that almost every page is using their own jquery.

In my Widget I use noConfilct mode, but seems, that jQuery is not defined (second error here)

Now my question is, is it possible to make this requirejs Widget independent, so that I can place it on any website without destroy the existing code there? Or which is it better without requirejs.

This is my main.js file:

```
// require js config
requirejs.config({
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery': 'noconflict'
        },
        'noconflict': {
            'jquery': 'jquery'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min',
            'jquery-1.10.2.min'
        ],
        'moment': 'moment.min',
        'moment-timezone': 'moment-timezone.min',
        'moment-timezone-data': 'moment-timezone-data',
        'momentDe': 'moment.de.min',
        'pikaday': 'pikaday',
        'placeholder': 'placeholder.min',
        'spinner': 'spin.min',
        'get': 'get'
    },

});


// initialize widget
require(['get', 'widget'], function () {
    //var $ = require('jquery');

    var Widget = require('widget');
    var widget = new Widget();

    //widget.doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to isolate your widget function you should use anonymous function; in this way your code doesn’t clash with any other JavaScript code included on the host page

```
(function() {
    //  anonymous function

})();
```

to check if jquery is loaded

```
var jQuery;

if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== 'version to check e.g.1.8.1') {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src",
        "url to your jquery file");
    if (script.readyState) {
      script.onreadystatechange = function () { //old versions IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
          }
      };
    } else { // Other browsers
      script.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // jQuery version is ok
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    call your function();
}
```

refer this nice [post](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/) for documentation

Comment: @chrisツ let me know.. for any help I'm here

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the great link! I think its really helpfull. Do you know it is possible using requirejs with anonymous functions? I think I'll refrain from requirejs, dont know if it the right tool for something like this...!?

Comment: I think yes, as you can load jquery you can load any script and then use it in the function that you call after every include. If you post a fiddle that doesn't work I will help you to get it wotk!